# Radio button limiting sets

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I have never done this and am not even sure where to post. I'm sorry.

I added another section to this set of three radio buttons on a really old website.  I believe I named it rdoSheetfedPressMats0  Is this the correct code?

It is still allowing me to select more than one.  What I added is in bold.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
private bool preventMoreThanOnePressMatSelection()
{
    if (rdoSheetfedPressMats.SelectedIndex != -1 && 
        rdoWebPressMats.SelectedIndex != -1 && 
        rdoSheetfedPressMats0.SelectedIndex != -1)  
    {
        rdoSheetfedPressMats.SelectedIndex = -1;
        rdoWebPressMats.SelectedIndex = -1;
        rdoSheetfedPressMats0.SelectedIndex = -1;

        lblRawMatsSelect.Text = "You can only select one raw material type.";
        lblAdditionalValSum.Text += "<br />- You can only select one raw material type.";
        lblRawMatsSelect.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        lblRawMatsSelect.Font.Italic = lblRawMatsSelect.Font.Bold = true;
        return false;
    }
    else if (rdoSheetfedPressMats.SelectedIndex == -1 && 
        rdoWebPressMats.SelectedIndex == -1 && chkUsedInPress.Checked)
    {
        lblRawMatsSelect.Text = "Select a raw material type.";
        lblAdditionalValSum.Text += "<br />- Select a raw material type.";
        lblRawMatsSelect.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        lblRawMatsSelect.Font.Italic = lblRawMatsSelect.Font.Bold = true;
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        lblRawMatsSelect.Text = string.Empty;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Radio buttons by their definition should only ever allow one selection in a group. Are your radio buttons not grouped properly?

Comment: I don't know.  There were the first two groups that worked fine. I'm trying to add a third group.  I copied in Design mode the second group and renamed it.  It still seems to be part of the second group, and not a distinct group, and I'm not sure how to do that. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not finding anything about grouping.  It's so old it doesn't help, either.  Would that be in the .aspx code of the page?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton.groupname(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you. I can try to do it that way, but it's not set up like that at all.   There's just this...                                                                                                             protected void rdoSheetfedPressMats_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {
        preventMoreThanOnePressMatSelection();
    }               This website is really old and I'm having trouble understanding it.

Comment: GroupName is a property that can be set in the designer (so, on the WebForms markup) or in the code-behind, if the controls are created there. The GroupName is what lets the ASPX engine know which radiobuttons are part of a group.